# How to boost Entity Framework with c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework. I recently Created a database and then added a database model and started coding with it. But it is very very very slow.

Here are my classes:

```
public partial class AssetList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Barcode { get; set; }

    public bool IsExist { get; set; }
}

private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Stopwatch swTotal = null;

        #region ADO select command
        swTotal = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        DataView dv = new SQL().GetDV("select * from AssetLists");
        AssetList al = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < dv.Count; i++)
        {
            al = new AssetList();
            al.Id = int.Parse(dv[i]["Id"].ToString());
            al.Name = dv[i]["Name"].ToString();
            al.Barcode = dv[i]["Barcode"].ToString();
            al.IsExist = bool.Parse(dv[i]["IsExist"].ToString());

            dgAssetList.Items.Add(al);
        }

        swTotal.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("ADO select command time: {0:N4} seconds.", swTotal.Elapsed.TotalSeconds));
        #endregion


        #region Entity Framework
        swTotal = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        using (var db = new dbModelContext())
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            //1
            //IQueryable<AssetList> QUERY = from a in db.AssetLists
            //            where a.Id == 1
            //            select a;

            //2
            //var QUERY = from a in db.AssetLists
            //            where a.Id == 1
            //            select a;

            //3
            var QUERY = db.AssetLists.Select(a => new { a.Id, a.Name, a.Barcode, a.IsExist });
            //.Where(a => a.Name.Contains("Asset"))
            //.Where(a => a.Id < 5);


            dgAssetList.ItemsSource = QUERY.ToList();
        }

        swTotal.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Entity Framework time: {0:N4} seconds.", swTotal.Elapsed.TotalSeconds));

        #endregion
    }
```

Messages are here:

ADO select command time: 0/0663 seconds.

Entity Framework time: 5/0479 seconds.

> Entity Framework time is decreasing each time I restart my app. I mean at the first time it was over 5 seconds, after that it became 3 and then it is 2. I wait some minutes and then I started the app and it is again 3 seconds.

I guess this increase and decrease is because of network but why `ADO select command time` always is about 0/06 seconds and won't change?

`dgAssetList` is a DataGrid.I had googled some approaches but I couldn't boost it up.

Does anyone know what is wrong with my codes?

Comment: How many records are in the table? Here you basically do a select all. Have you determined that it is indeed EF that is slow? EF is not known to be the fastest, but something simple shouldn't take long.

Comment: @bump Only 6 rows with 4 columns.

Comment: Slow database typically means bad schema, missing indexes and/or bad coding. Besides, what do you mean slow? How did you measure this? Why do you think it's EF's fault?

Comment: @MostafaKhodakarami is Sql Server local? Could be a network issue, no way EF is that slow for 6 records..

Comment: What do you mean with "slow"?

Comment: Why your POCO class is partial and ProxyCreationEnabled = false? Try to remove this features.

Comment: Can you set up a trace on the database? How long is the query EF issues actually taking? What is actually taking a long time - the initial startup or pressing the button every time?

Comment: @MostafaKhodakarami use LinqPad to run that query and see what happens.

Comment: Judging from this code, there is no reason for this to take long. Some thoughts: 1. Profile the app to exactly determine where the lag stems from (by adding Debug.WriteLines of DateTime.Nows for instance). 2. Check which query is being fired by EF to SQL (in VS Ultimate you can see the query, maybe in other versions as well, otherwise check with SQL profiler). 3. Finally, you could try to get the data via a SqlCommand to bypass EF, to check whether that shows the same lag.

Comment: I mean over 5 seconds for only 6 records in a database that has only one table. No indexing is required for such sample tiny data. Also I checked network speed and it's normal(copy speed is 30 MB/s). I checked the ADO select command "Select * from ..." and that was greatly fast. So it is really slow and I don't know what is the reason.

Comment: You may want to profile what takes the time. Depending on the used EF features, eg only the initial access may be slow (model/query compilation,db migrations check,...) is it only slow for  the first access?

Comment: Well, I think we can say that EF is not slow as a technology - its used in many systems. So the problem is in your code or in your database.

1) Profile your SQL Call using SQL Profiler 
2) Profile your .net Code using VS.net Profiler

These will tell you what is taking the time. It wont be EF. When you have identified the area of your code which is taking up time I will be able to give further advice.

Comment: I modified question and added ADO and times.I tested SQL Profiler and I see no other transaction is executing. I will test VS.net profiler.

Comment: @MostafaKhodakarami do NOT measure against the first EF query unless you have done initialization before. EF does a lot of initialization on the first access... if you want to measure query performance, initialize your context before (you can just make a simple query first, and then measure the second one: just don't do -the same- query since EF can cache it)

Comment: thanks @Jcl. Entity Framework is faster than ADO-select-command after initializing. Please post your answer to be accepted.

Comment: There you go. Note that it should not be faster, but it may depend on the specific generated SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework does a lot of initialization when accesing a `DbContext` for the first time. By the looks of your testing code (and confirmed later in comments), you are measuring the performance of the first query.

Don't do that, let EF initialize before you measure query performance. To do so, instantiate a `DbContext` and make some query that can't be cached, for example:

```
using (var db = new dbModelContext())
{    
   int dummy = db.AssetLists.Count();
   Console.WriteLine(dummy); // <-- make 100% sure this is not optimized away
}
```

And then measure your queries afterwards.

There are other means of initializing, but making sure it can access the database and query to it are in my oppinion, preferred.

Answer (score 0):

`ToList()` is what is called an "eager" operation. Behind the scenes, EF builds a query but doesn't execute it until such an operation takes place.

In your case, you are retrieving all of the records in memory.

Consider paging your results, using operations `Skip(number of records)` and `Take(number of records)` before calling `ToList()`. The formula to calculate the number of records based on the specific page number is quite trivial.

Comment: But the OP says he fetches only 6 rows.

Comment: This answer was probably posted earlier than the comment. You are right,  there is definitely something else going on.